# Как описать обработчик для кнопки используя Jquery?

Tags: jquery

Добрый день, Стэковерфлоучане, разбираюсь с Jquery,  вот написал метод, при загрузке страницы получаю данные с сервера и отображаю данные на странице:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $.get("api/getNotices", function (data) {
          var array = data;
          $.each(data, function (i, product) {
              content = '<p>' + product.Title + '</p>';
              content += '<p>' + product.Description + '</p>';
              content += '<button id="readAll">Read all</button>'
              $(content).appendTo("#textDiv");
          });
     });
});
```

В цикле я добавляю кнопку "Прочитать все..", как на эту кнопку написать оработчик?
Я пробовал написать стандартный обработчик по id:

```
$(function () {
      $("#readAll").button().click(function () {
          console.log("It works");
      });
});
```

Но по нажатию ничего не происходит, помогите советов.
Заранее спасибо за ваши ответы!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не назначайте одинаковые `id` разным элементам.

Используйте делегирование событий для элементов, которые будут созданы в дальнейшем.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $("body").on("click", ".readAll", function () {
    console.log("It works");
  });

  $.get("api/getNotices", function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (i, product) {
      var content = '<p>' + product.Title + '</p>';
      content += '<p>' + product.Description + '</p>';
      content += '<button class="readAll">Read all</button>';
      $(content).appendTo("#textDiv");
    });
  });
});
```